# Notifications every 24h at specified hour

Tags: android, notifications

My code partially works. It shows if app was opened +/- 2h before time for notification, later it doesn't show any notification. Sometimes the notification doesn't show at time that they should.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
private static final int FIRST_NOTIFICATION = 9;
private static final int SECOND_NOTIFICATION = 17;


Timer t1;
Timer t2;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    t1 =new Timer();
   // t2 = new Timer();

    Log.d("Service","Service Started!");
    Date da = new Date();
    da.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(da.getHours()>=FIRST_NOTIFICATION){
        da.setDate(da.getDay()+1);
    }
    da.setHours(FIRST_NOTIFICATION);
    da.setMinutes(0);
    da.setSeconds(0);
    if(t1!=null) {
        t1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pushNotification();
            }
        }, da, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
    Date d2 = new Date();
    d2.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(d2.getHours()>=SECOND_NOTIFICATION){
        d2.setDate(d2.getDay()+1);
    }
    d2.setHours(SECOND_NOTIFICATION);
    d2.setMinutes(0);
    d2.setSeconds(0);
    if(t2!=null){
        t2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pushNotification();
            }
        },d2,24*60*60*1000);
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Service","Service Stoped!");

}



private void pushNotification(){
    List<HashMap<String,String>> episodes = loadEpisodes();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(episodes.size()>0&&episodes!=null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < episodes.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(episodes.get(i).get("serie") +" - "+episodes.get(i).get("name")+"\n");
        }
        String text = sb.toString();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Your new episodes!");
        builder.setContentText(text);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fragment",1);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

I was doing some changes and tried a few options but it wasn't work with different results.
I wan't it to never stop and shows everyday at specified hours.

EDIT:
I tried to make it with AlarmManager but it never shows notifications.
MainActivity.java

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent inte = new Intent(this,NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,inte,0);
    if(settings.getBoolean("backgroundRunning",true)){
       /*Intent intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
        bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(intent);*/
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);

    }
    else if(am!=null&&settings.getBoolean("backgroundRunning",true)){
        am.cancel(pi);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using AlarmManager? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: No reason, thanks i will try it :) In which cases should i use timer and which alarmmanager?

Comment: @KenWolf Can you check now with AlarmManager it never shows notifications now.